# Dropping a session upon page load

Tags: php, session

I have a checkout system I created. Whenever someone has submitted their order I take them to another page that thanks them for their order and gives them a brief summary of what they ordered. It is called orderconfirmation.php. In that page I have an unset session script that I use to stop the shopping cart session. The only thing is, the session doesn't stop right on the page load. I can tell because my shopping cart quantity counter that I have on every page still shows items in the cart. They have to leave that page in order for the unset script to leave. After someone pays for their order and still sees that, they become a little confused, so I would need the shopping cart session to end when the page goes to the orderconfirmation.php page.

This is my code on the orderconfirmation.php page to unset the session:

```
//Initialize shopping cart session
if(!isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array();
}
// Empty cart
            unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);
```

Is their another approach I can do to unset the session when this page is loaded?

Shopping Cart Quantity Counter

```
//Shopping Cart Quantity Count

    if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
    $totalquantity = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] AS $product) {
        $totalquantity = $totalquantity + $product['quantity'];
    }
  }
  else {
       $totalquantity = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

on orderconfirmation page, if you rely on the session variable content to fetch the orderdetails data from database. then You can't unset the variable on page load. but if you don't need it on orderconfirmation page.. then you should just unset it on the last page right before redirecting to this orderconfirmation page.

Comment: There's no other way to still load data from the shopping cart session and then to kill the session after it has outputted those figures...then wipe the shopping car quantity counter to 0?

Comment: can you give the code upto that cart quantity part. i think there is more to it than this unset issue

Comment: I updated my question and added the code for the cart quantity counter.

Comment: I have that code in a file called loadProducts.php that I require on every page of my site, so that the customer can constantly see what is in their cart.